# How to add extra data to a comment/description in a contact/feedback form PHP?

Tags: php

I have a little experience in php and I am making a website for my client who needs contact form in their website. The question that i am about to ask is difficult, but your suggesitions are valuable.

I have a PHPcontact form(got from net),it is working perfectly. The question is my client wants to add extra datas into the comment/description section in the contact/feedback form which will be not visible to the person who sends the messages.

Example:
 contact form is like this

```
     Name:kevin
     Email:example@gmail.com
     Comment:This is  an exmaple comment
```

when this message will reach to my clients email it should be like this

```
     from:example@gmail.com
     subject: feedback from customer
     Comment: This is an example comment.


      Please forward this mail to .....section and contact to .....
      phone no:0000000000
      email: exampele@example.com 
      OR
      code:4540560ndjdjdd ( a serialnumber generated from an external php file)
```

if you know how to do this please explain it.

Comment: Your are charging people money for something you know zip about. I think you should give your client his money back and go by a basic html book instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the value from the form, put it on the php mail + your new values/hidden value
So, the user will not see it like:

> ```
>  from:example@gmail.com
>  subject: feedback from customer
>  Comment: This is an example comment.
>
>
>  Please forward this mail to .....section and contact to .....
>  phone no:0000000000
>  email: exampele@example.com 
>  OR
>  code:4540560ndjdjdd ( a serialnumber generated from an external php file)
> ```

```
<?php
$msg = "from:$_POST['email']
        subject:$_POST['subject']
        Comment:$_POST['comment']


        Please forward this mail to .....section and contact to .....
        phone no:$phone_number
        email: $myemail
        OR
        code:$generated_code ( a serialnumber generated from an external php file)";
?>
```

Now you just need use mail() to send the value of $msg using POST details + your 'hidden' details.

If you want hidden in the form just use hidden attribute.

Try to explain your question better, would help a lot.

(in the $msg, if line break won't work try \n or br)